# Can the Xbox One controller work on PC games? Does X Padder software help make the Xbox One controller usable in PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one, xpadder

I recently purchased a Xbox One console, moving from the PC realm towards console gaming now, and was curious of support on the controller.

Are we able to connect the controller via PC and be able to play Steam games/other pc games?

Does [X Padder](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Xpadder.shtml)   work in this instance, can I emulate keyboard/mouse controls over to my Xbox One controller?

Is there a plugin, software, or a set of instructions in enabling controller use?

Comment: there are no PC drivers for the Xbox One controller yet. I'm not sure what that means in relation to third party software, though.

Comment: I read that the X Padder software can map keys from the Xbox 360 controller from keys of a keyboard and mouse... was wondering if this could be replicated into the xbox one controller

Comment: @Aonepathan - Once there are drivers it be able to.  Of course once there are drivers you shouldn't have to use Xpadder unless its a game without any controller support.

Comment: Official drivers have been released. Check my answer for an update and links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Yes, drivers have been published that will allow you to run on PC, hence, no need for any third-party software! [[Source]](http://majornelson.com/2014/06/05/pc-drivers-for-the-xbox-one-controller-available-now/)

You can download the drivers for different build by using the links below or from [Major Nelson's post](http://majornelson.com/2014/06/05/pc-drivers-for-the-xbox-one-controller-available-now/) I linked above as source.

- [PC Drivers for Xbox One Controller (x86)](http://mjr.mn/XboxOnePCDriversx86)
- [PC Drivers for Xbox One Controller (x64)](http://mjr.mn/XboxOnePCDriversx64)

**Original dating back before 6 June 2014**

No. The communication protocol the One controller uses is different from the communication protocol the 360 controller uses. This was needed to make several improvements such as reduced latency and more support for state messages for giving the console more control over the controller's state (it will put the controller in a low power state if you are not holding it).

But as you noted, all these improvements come at a cost. Until the time that someone comes up with a driver for the controller to be used on PC, there is nothing you can do. As X Padder relies on the protocol in use, it too won't be able to solve your issue. That being said, there supposedly is already a driver but because the protocol is likely protected by a patent, the driver would infringe on it. You can read some about it on [this US Gamer article](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/hacker-gets-xbox-one-controller-working-on-pc).

Comment: It's not about the protocol per say it's simply about the driver

Comment: I see... so overall this is a software issue. And chances are we await a future release of a protocol/driver to install in our PC's to enable the controller. Darn. I'll continue researching just in case such a thing exists yet. Thanks for your responses guys, pretty much answers the question!

Comment: You can't *copyright* a communication protocol. It is not itself a work "fixed in a tangible medium" as required by copyright law; it is a process and a set of rules. However, you can *patent* a communication protocol or other process. More information on Wikipedia: [Idea–expression divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_divide)

Comment: Indeed, bad wording on my side, I meant patent not copyright! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: nice job updating answer with official drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the update as well, appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

Xbox One Gamepad Driver Release (0.1)

http://lucasassis.com/

Comment: Can you add a little more information? What is this? How will it help?

Comment: Why would anyone use an unofficial driver when the official one is released?